# Text Spill over in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a text View "Value4". Sometime the value is more that the value it can accommodate. I need to know if there is anyway If I can move the value from text View "Value4" to text View "Box 5".

[image]

Comment: Do you want to move the whole value or just the part that does not fit and why do you want to do this?

Comment: Part of it which does not fit

Comment: wouldn't you rather wrap your text to go to the next line of your Value 4 field?

Comment: It is getting wrapped to next line but the next line is not visible as we have restricted the size of the field "Value4"

Comment: Why not remove box 5 and then extend value 4 to take up that space, or does box 5 serve another purpose?

Answer (score 0):

**This might help:**

[How do I tell if my textview has been ellipsized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005933/how-do-i-tell-if-my-textview-has-been-ellipsized)

check if **value4** is `ellipsized`. If yes, remove the Text from **value4** and put it in **Box5**