# Issue with handling click on Expandable textview

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have an expandable text view which has a "view more " option. To which i can specify maxChars to be shown instead of maxLine.

I have made some modification to the code present here:
[Detect if TextVIew is ellipsized before layout is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069895/detect-if-textview-is-ellipsized-before-layout-is-shown/20072257?noredirect=1#comment41329494_20072257)

My requirement is that if chars ==200 show the text as it is.. if maxChars > 200 then show "see more" option. Once the text is expanded(hide "view more" text), if user clicks on the text anywhereit should compress again with displaying 200 chars with "view more" at the end of it . I tried it, but facing problem while setting click listener to the whole text. As even "see more" spanned text listens to the click event.

Can someone help me with this!

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("demotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotextdemotext");
TextViewResizable(textView,16,"See More");

      public void TextViewResizable(final TextView tv,final int maxCharacter, final String expandText) {
        if (tv.getTag() == null) {
            tv.setTag(tv.getText());
        }
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if (tv.getText().length() < maxCharacter) {
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0,tv.getText().length())+ " " + expandText;
                    tv.setText(text);
                    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    tv.setText(addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, expandText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                } else if (tv.getText().length() >= maxCharacter) {
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0,maxCharacter)+ " " + expandText;
                    tv.setText(text);
                    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                    tv.setText(addClickablePartTextViewResizable(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()), tv, expandText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePartTextViewResizable(final Spanned strSpanned, final TextView tv, final String expandText) {
        String str = strSpanned.toString();
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(strSpanned);

        if (str.contains(expandText)) {
            ssb.setSpan(new Spannable(Color.BLUE, true) {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View widget) {
                            tv.setLayoutParams(tv.getLayoutParams());
                            tv.setText(tv.getTag().toString(),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                            tv.invalidate();
                        }
                    }, str.indexOf(expandText), str.indexOf(expandText)+ expandText.length(), 0);

        }
        return ssb;

    }

    class Spannable extends ClickableSpan {

        private int color = -1;
        private float fontSize = -1;
        private boolean isUnderline = true;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable(float fontSize) {
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable(boolean isUnderline) {
            this.isUnderline = isUnderline;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable(int color, boolean isUnderline) {
            this.isUnderline = isUnderline;
            this.color = color;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public Spannable(int color, float fontSize) {
            this.color = color;
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
        }

        /**
         * Overrides methods
         */
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

            if (color != -1) {
                ds.setColor(color);
            }
            if (fontSize > 0) {
                ds.setTextSize(fontSize);
            }

            ds.setUnderlineText(isUnderline);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am able to achieve the 200 chars limit. It also expands to show all the text. The issue i am facing is to click on the text anywhere and compress it to show 200 again with "view more" option

Comment: Any update on the above question? I am facing issue with handling onclick on the spanned text and the normal text in the textview. i need to handle the onclick on both of them separately