# When is layout not null when creating view Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making my own custom view and having trouble accessing the layout object immediately after initializing it.

I understand the documentation says layout can be null. But is there a certain event which I can override which will tell me when it's available? I've seen answers on SO which recommend adding a ViewTreeObserver ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558948/how-to-use-textview-getlayout-it-returns-null))

It seems weird to me that I would need a separate class to know when the layout is available. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, there exist no such method which you can override to know when the layout is available. If you find ViewTreeObserver difficult, you can try posting a runnable in the UI Thread i.e.,

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = view.getHeight();
            int width = view.getWidth();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the initialization of the layouts occurs in `onCreate()` so it would be better if you try the below code in `onResume()` whether the custom layout is available or not.

if the custom layout is `custom_layout.xml` then try the below code

```
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
if(view!=null)
{
    //Place your code over here
}
```

Comment: I'm not if I'm understanding correctly, but I'm trying to access the layout object from the view itself, not from the activity which is creating the view, so I don't think onCreate() or onResume() are relevant functions, right?