# getLineStart() always return null for my TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` and I want to get some specific line's text of it but when I use `txt.getLayout.getLineStart(1)` it returns null and crashes the app, what is the reason?

```
TextView txt = (TextView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
int start = txt.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
int end =  txt.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
String first = txt.getText().subSequence(start,end).toString();
```

Crash log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sattva.animalsencyclopedia, PID: 11244
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.sattva.animalsencyclopedia.fragments.FragmentInformation.onViewCreated(FragmentInformation.java:110)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show code with logcat  please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have edited the post

Comment: simply check what `txt.getLayout()` returns...

Comment: @pskink it returns null

Comment: so you have answered your own question

Comment: @pskink so why it returns null ?

Comment: from the docs: `returns Layout the Layout that is currently being used to display the text. This can be null if the text or width has recently changes.`

Comment: @pskink so probably he should make TextView as a final?

Comment: @Kostya no, basically he tried to call `getLayout` too early

Comment: @pskink I added comment in my answer that he should call this code in onStart or onResume, so I hope it will help with problem

Comment: @pskink im in a fragment , where should i call it ?

Comment: ask uncle google for: `android getLayout null`

Comment: Nothing changed when I used it in onResume or. ..

Comment: Did you try solution from here? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558948/how-to-use-textview-getlayout-it-returns-null

Comment: @Kostya yes it doesnt work either

Comment: run [this](http://pastebin.com/nPDFx8za) and watch the `logcat`

Comment: @pskink yes it got solved thank you very muuuuch

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't find this view using `findViewById()` method in correct way. You are using fragment and probable you have something like `getActivity().findViewById()`. Try in your `onCreateView()` method do something like this `view.findViewById()`, where `view` is the result of inflating.

As @pskink mentioned from the docs: `returns Layout the Layout that is currently being used to display the text. This can be null if the text or width has recently changes.` Try to call this code in onStart or onCreate method, but you should make a `txt` as a class member variable.

```
int start = txt.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
int end =  txt.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
String first = txt.getText().subSequence(start,end).toString();
```

Comment: What is this mRootView? Probably it has null

Comment: mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_informations, container, false); @kostya

Comment: Try to call 2,3,4 line in onStart or onResume

Comment: txt is the textview,How could i make it global ? @kostya

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean class member variable. You should use TextView txt; as a member field and not in onCreate or other methods.