# move cursor in editText with buttons android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-button, android-cursor

i'm developing an application for android studio. I added buttons to move the cursor left and right, how can I also move it up and down between the lines?
This is what I have already done:

**EditText editText;
ImageButton buttonBackward, buttonForward;
RelativeLayout arrows;**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    buttonBackward = findViewById(R.id.buttonBackward);
    buttonForward = findViewById(R.id.buttonForward);
    arrows = findViewById(R.id.arrows);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arrows.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    buttonForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getSelectionEnd() < editText.getText().toString().length()) {
                editText.setSelection(editText.getSelectionEnd() + 1);
            } else {
                //fine stringa, non posso muovere il cursore
            }
        }
    });
    buttonBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getSelectionStart() > 0) {
                editText.setSelection(editText.getSelectionEnd() - 1);
            } else {
                //start of string, cannot move cursor backward
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291446/9932178) will help you.

Comment: Have you try android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."  ? have a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android

Comment: hello, thanks anyway but I have to move the cursor in the same edittext and not between two different edittext