# How to change the ellipsis string of Android TextView?(... to ...more)

Tags: android, textview, ellipse

I want to change the ellipsis string from `...` to custom string, such as `...[more]`.
But in TextUtil, the ellipsis string is fixed：

```java
private static final String ELLIPSIS_STRING = new String(ELLIPSIS_NORMAL);
```

Then how to change the ellipses?

Answer (score 8):

I was surprised that there isn't any good solution to that yet, so I spent sometime and wrote my own custom TextView which allows you to show a custom ellipsis. Few things I had in mind while developing it:

1. The TextView shouldn't draw the text more than once since this is a heavy operation and could compromise the performance.
2. It should respect Spanned strings.
3. Support custom text color for the ellipsis.

Have a look and let me know if you find any issues: https://github.com/TheCodeYard/EllipsizedTextView

And here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thx for the lib!
However, some issues. First, if the text content the default ellipsis, the ellipsis will be added at wrong position. 
Then, the lib use the `TextUtils.Ellipse()` which can give longer text, than the one displayed in the layout (when display on multiple lines).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [How to use custom ellipsis in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054717/how-to-use-custom-ellipsis-in-android-textview). But you must run the function after layout, you can run it on OnGlobalLayoutListener.onGlobalLayout() or view.post().

Answer (score 0):

Try  This Method

```
 public  void CustomEllipsize(final TextView tv, final int maxLine, final String ellipsizetext) {

    if (tv.getTag() == null) {
        tv.setTag(tv.getText());
    }
    ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if ((maxLine+1) <= 0) {
                int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - ellipsizetext.length()) + " " + ellipsizetext;
                tv.setText(text);
            } else if (tv.getLineCount() >= (maxLine+1)) {
                int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd((maxLine+1) - 1);
                String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - ellipsizetext.length()) + " " + ellipsizetext;
                tv.setText(text);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

and use this method like this

```
    final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    String dummyText = "sdgsdafdsfsdfgdsfgdfgdfgsfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgdfgsfdgsfdgfdsdfsdfsdf";
    txtView.setText(dummyText);
    CustomEllipsize(txtView, 2, "...[more]");
```

Comment: It will be ellipsis in the max line, no matter need or not.