# how to change text if is Ellipsized in android textView

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, android-handler, ellipsis

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008755/311130) on how to check if text is ellipsized.

I want to programatically change the text if it's `ellipsized`.

however, if I use callback in `textView.post()` the text change will be seen in the UI for the user or cause performance issues.

**side comment:**

I have tried to measure text width and view width in `treeObserver.preDraw()` but there is a case I see when debugging that both width are equal and nevertheless the text is replaced when it's not truncated.

replacing the condition to `textWidth < viewWidth` makes few cases of `non-ellipsized` text to still be replaced by shorter one.

```
final ViewTreeObserver[] viewTreeObserver = {myAccountView.getViewTreeObserver()};
viewTreeObserver[0].addOnPreDrawListener(
    new OnPreDrawListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onPreDraw() {
        int chipWidth =
            myAccountView.getMeasuredWidth()
                - myAccountView.getPaddingLeft()
                - myAccountView.getPaddingRight();
        if (chipWidth > 0) {
          myAccountView.setText(
              setChipTextWithCorrectLength(
                  getContext().getString(R.string.desc_long_length),
                  getContext().getString(R.string.desc_meduim_length),
                  getContext().getString(R.string.short_length),
                  chipWidth));
          viewTreeObserver[0] = myAccountView.getViewTreeObserver();
          if (viewTreeObserver[0].isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver[0].removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: @Onik yes, shorter text instead of ellipsizing. Any idea?

Comment: @Onik I need to use one line only

Comment: @Onik but that's not my goal. i want to replace for shorter text when ellipsized.

Comment: Uuupps, sorry, forgot. So I guess measuring is what's left. If I have time tomorrow, I'll try to look at it.