# Android layout - align text to right if one line, otherwise align to left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How do I align text to the right if it is only one line, but otherwise align to the left (so that new lines start from the left, not right)? Is it possible to do it in the xml (non-programatically)?

What I want:

[image]

[image]

What I have:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"   
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/label"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Totally there's 4 Textviews?

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005933/how-do-i-tell-if-my-textview-has-been-ellipsized) could help you.

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah No, 2. I edited the question to better show images. There are two cases shown: one and mulit-line textviews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this behaviour you need to have the properties `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"`, `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` and  `layout_width="wrap_content"` into the content (@+id/content) `TextView`.

**Xml Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Small content text:**

[image: small_text]

**Long content text:**

[image: long_text]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="start"
               android:layout_gravity="end"
               android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
```